# Sample data (time series) with varying dimensions in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am building a training set consisting of two types of stellar flares and planning to use SVM as the classification algorithm. My training samples are time series of varying lengths. There are about 500 samples in total. The shortest is 20 minutes (corresponds to 20 points in the x-direction), and the longest is 70 minutes. I have worked with SVM in the past but only when the training samples are of the same dimension so I am a bit confused working with this data.

```
 sample1 = [228421.97, 228412.2, 226350.36, 228682.45, 235230.8, 249476.31, 295342.9, 305726.47, 306297.34, 317928.06, 331425.4, 327457.47, 319601.56, 313681.66, 306458.88, 300534.8, 293425.3, 288308.03, 283743.7, 279555.72, 275912.3, 272426.12, 269431.3, 266490.78, 263824.62, 261392.8, 258859.69, 256228.75, 255648.2, 254316.77, 251989.42, 250020.62, 247674.14, 246597.3, 244943.7, 244279.78, 243340.23, 242705.12, 241383.89, 239908.98, 238534.95, 236921.12, 235440.22, 234578.12, 233270.67, 232202.02, 231123.97, 230130.36, 229262.83, 228603.64, 227440.86, 227012.31, 226822.05, 225729.5]

 sample2 = [267696.7, 267586.12, 268090.72, 268305.1, 268942.22, 269092.88, 269458.84, 269155.94, 268905.47, 268673.03, 268369.0, 268508.2, 268662.9, 268685.78, 268573.16, 268199.78, 268328.06, 268362.0, 268146.84, 268436.38, 268229.38, 268249.28, 268337.03, 268758.3, 268743.12, 268490.2, 268568.16, 268580.66, 268372.88, 268252.2, 268331.72, 268195.72, 268362.84, 268026.47, 268039.1]
```

The two samples above are to demonstrate the differences in size of the training set samples. The strategy I am thinking of now is to interpolate so that every sample has exactly 70 entries, equal to the longest one but I am not sure if that's optimal in this case.

I would really appreciate any suggestions and/or leads to relevant literature so I can study this.

Comment: I am not sure if using SVM for a sequential problem be a very good idea. Didn't you want to use some sort of Markov chains instead? If you insist on using SVM, I will ask if each position of the feature has the same meaning?  I mean the 2nd feature in the vector of length 20 has the same meaning as the 2nd feature in the vector of length 70? and for the similarity, what you will use? like a cosine similarity in the kernel?

Comment: @alift I don't really have much experience in the machine learning department (I am working on an astrophysics project and I came up with the idea of using ML on my data just recently), but I have played with this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/keplersmachines/kepler-labelled-time-series-data, which is time series and can be pretty well classified using only linear SVM. So it's really just an educated guess that SVM can deal with my data, which is also Kepler time series.